# Even or Odd for factorial

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, contest-math, factorial

> **Moderator Note:** This was a contest question on [codechef.com](http://www.codechef.com/IOPC2014/problems/IOPC14A).

Given $N$ and $M$ I need to tell whether $\left\lfloor \large\frac{N!}{M} \right\rfloor$ is even or odd.How to do this question?

Provided $N\le10^5$ and $M\le10^{18}$

EXAMPLE :  If $N=3$ and $M=2$ then answer is " Even "

Comment: Is this a programming question?.

Comment: @boywholived yeah..an algorithm or a formula would do work i guess

Comment: Look at how many factors of 2 are in each and use that, along with other basic ideas like is N!>M. I'd note that 3!/2 = 6/2 = 3 which is Odd, at least in my world of arithmetic. With N=3, M=2 there is 1 2 factor in each which cancel out giving an odd result.

Comment: If $N>3$ and $M<N$ then the answer is even.

Comment: @JBKing Please explain in detail

Comment: Is $\lfloor 6/2\rfloor$ really even ???

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By the rule of integer division,

$$M.q=N!-N!\bmod M,$$
where we are interested in the parity of the quotient $q$.

We can rewrite

$$M.(2.(q\text{ div }2)+q\bmod 2)=N!-N!\bmod M.$$

Then, taking the $\bmod 2$,

$$(M\bmod2).(q\bmod2)=(N!-N!\bmod M)\bmod2.$$

Now, assuming $M$ odd, the parity of $q$ can be obtained as the parity of $N!-N!\bmod M$, which can be computed using modular arithmetic.

If $M$ is even, one can simplify $M$ and $N!$ by the suitable power of $2$.

Remark: in most cases (and certainly when $N>63$), the term $N!$ keeps an even contribution after simplification and can be ignored.